# Creating a Dropdown list based in another field in same form - Sharepoint 2013 List

Tags: sharepoint

Guys!

I have a Sharepoint List, and I'm struggling to customize the webpart to include a new Item.

The need is to create a Dropbox that changes values based in another field in same webform.

[image: Example of List Form]

Here in this list, I select the Coordinator list, but the problem is I really don't know how to show in Analyst field just the analysts from the coordinator I just choose.

Note: We are using a workspace in Sharepoint 2013, and due adm restrictions we can only use the regular settings, so we can't create custom HTML webparts for example.

Comment: Just adding a comment, I had searched many topics, and what I found was jscript solutions (that we are unable to implement), and "VLOOKUP" solutions that are not in FORM Selection "time".

Comment: Have you seen this solution? https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices/wiki/SPCascadeDropdowns

Comment: Hi Yannic, tks I will try this on monday, but I believe I can’t implement because of restrictions from my company, I have only access to web front-end editions

Comment: May work, just insert a script editor webpart with the references that you need